# Flink ParquetSinkWriter FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-flink, parquet

I am trying to use Apache Flink write parquet file on HDFS by using BucketingSink and a custom ParquetSinkWriter.

Here is the code and above error indicate when enable checking point (call snapshotState() in BucketingSink Class) flush method from below is not quiet working. Even writer is closed with "writer.close();" but still got error from "writer = createWriter();". Any thoughts? thanks

Got error like this:

> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException:
>   /user/hive/flink_parquet_fils_with_checkingpoint/year=20/month=2/day=1/hour=17/_part-4-9.in-progress
>   for client 192.168.56.202 already exists 
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3003)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2890)
>
> ....
>   .
>   at flink.untils.ParquetSinkWriter.flush(ParquetSinkWriterForecast.java:81)
>    at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.snapshotState(BucketingSink.java:749)

```
import org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.CompressionCodecName;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Parquet writer.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class ParquetSinkWriter<T extends GenericRecord> implements Writer<T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -975302556515811398L;

    private final CompressionCodecName compressionCodecName = CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY;
    private final int pageSize = 64 * 1024;

    private final String schemaRepresentation;

    private transient Schema schema;
    private transient ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer;
    private transient Path path;

    private int position;

    public ParquetSinkWriter(String schemaRepresentation) {
        this.schemaRepresentation = Preconditions.checkNotNull(schemaRepresentation);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(FileSystem fs, Path path) throws IOException {
        this.position = 0;
        this.path = path;

        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }

        writer = createWriter();
    }

    @Override
    public long flush() throws IOException {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(writer);
        position += writer.getDataSize();
        writer.close();
        writer = createWriter();

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getPos() throws IOException {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(writer);
        return position + writer.getDataSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
            writer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(T element) throws IOException {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(writer);
        writer.write(element);
    }

    @Override
    public Writer<T> duplicate() {
        return new ParquetSinkWriter<>(schemaRepresentation);
    }

    private ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> createWriter() throws IOException {
        if (schema == null) {
            schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaRepresentation);
        }

        return AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord>builder(path)
            .withSchema(schema)
            .withDataModel(new GenericData())
            .withCompressionCodec(compressionCodecName)
            .withPageSize(pageSize)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file You are trying to create currently exists. This is because You are using the default write mode `CREATE`, which fails when the file exists. What You can try to do is change Your code to use the `OVERWRITE` mode. You can change the `createWriter()` method to return something like below:

```
return AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord>builder(path)
            .withSchema(schema)
            .withDataModel(new GenericData())
            .withCompressionCodec(compressionCodecName)
            .withPageSize(pageSize)
            .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE)
            .build();
```